# How do you query a custom post type (CPT) via an ACF relationship field?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

#### Overview

I have two `CTPs`:

1. `Range`: Which showcases 4 van types
2. `Wheels` Which showcases all wheels a van can have.

In the `wheels` post type, I have two `ACF fields`:

1. Image: Which is of type `image` (an image of the wheel). The `name` of this field is `image`
2. Available on: Which is a `relationship` field where we can select which vans (from the `range` post type) this `wheel` is available on. The `name` of this field is `available_on_range`

Now, I'm querying `range` by `id` for each page and want to pull in all of the wheels that have this `range` in its relationship field.

For example, allow `wheel` 7 is available on `range`/van 1, but not on `range`/van 4.

#### Current problem

My `relationship` field is working, as I'm able to get and output the wheel name (`post_title`), however, I can't seem to get the `image` for that wheel (no `src`).

#### Code

```html
<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'range',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'p'  => $select_range, // id of post
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$title = "";

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
  global $post;
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $title =  get_the_title();
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

$related_wheels = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'wheels',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'available_on_range', // name of custom field
      'value' => '"' . $select_range . '"',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
));

?>

<div class="options-wheels">
  <?php
  if( $related_wheels ):
    foreach( $related_wheels as $wheel ):
      $wheel_name = $wheel->post_title;
      $wheel_image = get_field("image");

      ?>
      <div class="configurator__options-wheel">
        <img src="<?php echo $wheel_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $wheel_name; ?>" loading="lazy"/>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;
  endif;
  ?>
</div>
```

A `var_dump($wheel_image)` returns `NULL`.

How can I get the `image`?

#### Have also tried

- `<img src="<?php echo the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $wheel_name; ?>" loading="lazy"/>`
- `<img src="<?php echo esc_url($wheel_image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $wheel_name; ?>" loading="lazy"/>`

A `var_dump($wheel)` doesn't show anything related to the `image`:

```html
object(WP_Post)#2964 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(4363) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "2" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2022-05-18 11:00:08" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2022-05-18 11:00:08" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(7) "Wheel 1" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(4) "4363" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2022-05-18 14:02:47" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2022-05-18 14:02:47" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(45) "http://rev.test/?post_type=wheels&p=4363" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(6) "wheels" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }
```

Which means that there is an issue with my `$related_wheels` query. But, I only want to query `wheels` that match the `id` of the current page, which is what the query currently does. How do I make it show the `image` data also?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the get Image field like this.
The type of $wheel is object, so you couldn't use the method of getting value of array.

```
$wheel_image = get_field("image", $wheel->ID);
```

Then you can add image url to the Image tag.

```
<div class="configurator__options-wheel">
  <img src="<?php echo $wheel_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $wheel_name; ?>" loading="lazy"/>
</div>
```